# Define word with mixed case letters (upper/lower)

Tags: formatting, typography

I am using some acronym-like words in my text that actually do not have a phrase but have a standard way of writing, like a "brand". (for ex. MyWorD)

Is there a library for this or a way to define mixed case words and use them in text?
Like `\formattingcommand{myword}` resulting in `MyWorD`.

Something similar to the `\newacronym{myword}{MyWorD}{boohoo...}` glossary entry definition would be really nice.

Edit:

Thanks to MattAllegro's answer I tried some things with the `acronym` package. My problem was that I wanted to print my nomenclature so didn't want to have empty definitions for these mixed-case words. The other thing was to somehow avoid the first time printing of `definition (acronym)` format.

The second problem can be avoided by the `\acrshort{myword}` command. And since I am lazy, I wrapped it into a shorter command with `\newcommand{\glss}[1]{\acrshort{#1}}`.

The first one I solved by splitting the glossary in two files. One for the words with definitions which is going to be printed, and one for the mixed-case words.

If there is a nicer, cleaner way to do it I would love to know about it.

Comment: Is `\newcommand{\myword}{MyWorD}` too impractical? You would use it as `\myword` in the text.

Comment: Thank you Jonas, for my case it is a good solution, since there are only two words like this (for now).

Comment: For a more frequent use I guess something like the acronyms example would be cleaner than many command definitions. Would be interesting to know but then again I just started working with it :)

Comment: One thing to remember is the fact that commands without arguments eat any following whitespace, so `\myword next` will generate MyWorDnext. To preserve the space you can use `\myword\ next` or `\myword{} next`, or check the `xspace` package.

Comment: With an acronym definition, simply call `\acused{myword}` after defining it to make all future calls to `\ac{myword}` be given in the short format.

Answer (score 6):

I am not a top user but the first thing I thought was - just like Jonas suggests - something like:

```
\newcommand{\myword}{MyWorD}
```

or:

```
\newcommand{\MWD}{MyWorD}
```

or the `acronym` package.

Beware that TeX will ignore spaces after `\myword`, so `\myword{}` would be the way for typing it in your document to avoid this problem.

Comment: You don't need to be a *top* user of any kind to join in :) Also we have only a handful of them, they drink and trash the chat room. We are scared.... please send help.

Comment: @percusse I should flag your comment as “rude or offensive”. ;-)

Comment: The answer is good; I took the liberty of adding the usual caution about spaces after control sequences. Don't be afraid to answer! Of course, you being based in Bologna is a big defect…

Comment: Package `xspace` can fix the space after macro issue.